# OCaml type-inference of fun y z x -> x [z] y;;

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

I'm not sure i solved this correctly.
Can you help me?

```
fun y z x -> x [z] y;;
```

This was my idea:

```
fun 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> ....
```

Now, on the right side of -> should stay the function `x` that takes the list `[z]` as parameter and then takes the `y` as parameter. ok?
So the type of `x` is `: 'b list -> 'a -> 'c` ok?

So it becames: `'a -> 'b -> ('b list -> 'a -> 'c) ->` and then I just have to add the result of evaluation of `x [z] y` that is `'c` and i get in the end:

`'a -> 'b -> ('b list -> 'a -> 'c) -> 'c` Is it correct?

Comment: you could have just copied that first expression directly into the ocaml REPL and verify your work.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct, good job!